# Magento 1.9 show single item price when minimum order amount is 10

Tags: magento-1.9, price

On our webshop, we have a product that has a minimum order amount of 10.
However, this also makes Magento show the price of the item as 10 times the cost of a single item.

This scares off a lot of potential customers, as they think the item is very expensive.

Is there any way to have Magento show the single item price on the product page, and only show the total amount in the shopping cart and invoice?

Thanks in advance!